# pandas.dataframe groupby and transpose

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, transpose

I am a beginner at Python and Pandas. I have trouble putting words to my problem, so instead, here is a sample of my dataframe (there are more values and more columns as well):

```
Reason          Grade     
'course'        15
'home'          10
'reputation'    12
'other'         16
'other'         9
'home'          14
'reputation'    10
'reputation'    8
'course'        20
'home'          19
'course'        12
'other'         10
'home'          17
'reputation'    18
```

And, I will like to get this:

```
     course      home     reputation   other
       15         10          12        16
       20         14          10        9
       12         19          8         10
                  17          18
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried the df.groupby['Reason'] function?

Comment: Read about pandas `groupby`. What you are trying to achieve is quite simple.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, groupby has to go with a method on it, like `df.groupby("reason").sum()` or `df.groupby("reason").mean()` but I didn't find a method that would return me all the values for "count", "home", etc

Comment: @Dennis.M
The closest I got is I guess this: `dfT = df.groupby(["Reason","Grade"]).count().T` However, I don't get quite exactly what I wanted...

Comment: @floflim - how working answer?

Comment: @jezrael Your answer worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter by `Reason` column with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new column and last use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) - for not exist values are added missing values:

```
df = df.assign(count = df.groupby('Reason').cumcount()).pivot('count','Reason','Grade')
print (df)
Reason  'course'  'home'  'other'  'reputation'
count                                          
0           15.0    10.0     16.0          12.0
1           20.0    14.0      9.0          10.0
2           12.0    19.0     10.0           8.0
3            NaN    17.0      NaN          18.0
```